# What will happen if we merge the same changeset multiple times? - TFS

Tags: tfs

I have two branches: DEV and Main. What will happen if we merge the same changeset from DEV to Main branch multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This often happens in the case of a Partial Merge.

Sometimes these are obvious, e.g. You merge a change with 3 files, but revert 1, checking in only 2 files.

Sometimes I'm not sure why TFS things the whole change wasn't merged.

If you perform a track changeset of your changeset it should show as a partial merge.

[image]

Merging it a second time, should remove it from the list and bring over whatever was missing, sometimes this is just meta-data.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you merge changesets are only merged one time and they are removed from the merge list after.  Our team tries to merge everything at once and after that your merge list is essentially empty.  It is highly discouraged to cherry pick what changes you merge.